# How to register RoleManager in Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I run my application in debug mode my seed method fails because of a 'missing' service. The error message is:

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered.

Can someone please help me register this service correctly in the `StartUp.cs` class? Thanks!

### RolesConfig.cs

```
public static class RolesConfig
{

    public static async Task InitialiseAsync(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        string[] roleNames = {"Admin", "Report", "Search"};
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddHttpClient<IExceptionServiceClient, ExceptionServiceClient>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Comment: Where's your `ConfigureServices` method? Presuming you're using ASP.NET Core Identity, are you calling `services.AddDefaultIdentity()` anywhere?

Comment: Check this: [ASP.NET Core Identity: No service for role manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425850/asp-net-core-identity-no-service-for-role-manager)

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing how you've configured your services. In general, if you're getting a service-related exception, that is the first place to look.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have added Startup.cs now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need to add

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
        config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false; //optional
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; //optional
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

in your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

Comment: this works! many thanks. For anyone else using this answer don't forget to remove `services.AddDefaultIdentity<>`

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing the call the AddRoleManager. Here is a similar setup I had, try:

```
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(o => {
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `ConfigureServices` method, you're already calling `AddDefaultIdentity` which is a new addition in 2.1 that scaffolds Identity without role support. To add role support and therefore the `RoleManager` to your services collection modify your code as below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: With this method, this error was thrown
`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.`

Comment: The order in which the services are added matters too (in some cases). ``AddEntityFrameworkStores`` should be after ``AddRoles``

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the default identity

`services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()`