# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So I am fairly new to ASP.NET Core, always used ASP.NET MVC before. Now I want to create roles which I can assign to users. But it is giving me a hard time, already trying for 2 days :p I tried various tutorials and guides but I couldn't get it to work.

For this I followed this tutorial:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/role-base-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

I follow all of the steps and implemented it into my application. However it won't work. The error it is giving me:

"No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered."

I figured out that it has something to do with the configureservice method and that I have to register the RoleManager and IdentityRole in of the methods as the other methods can't recognize these properties.

My ConfigureServices method at the moment:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        //services.AddIdentity<???, IdentityRole>();
        //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
        //.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

The configure method at the moment:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
    }
```

And the CreateRoles method which I used from the linked tutorial above.

```
        private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //initialiseren van custom roles   
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Medewerker" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                //create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1  
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        //Probeer admin account te vinden
        IdentityUser admin = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@test.nl");

        //Als het admin account nog niet bestaat, maak hem dan aan
        if (admin == null)
        {
            admin = new IdentityUser()
            {
                UserName = "admin@test.nl",
                Email = "admin@test.nl",
            };
            //2de property is hier het wachtwoord
            await UserManager.CreateAsync(admin, "Ex4mple");
        }
        //Voeg de gebruiker toe aan de desbetreffende
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "Admin");

        //Probeer medewerker account te vinden
        IdentityUser medewerker = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("medewerker@test.nl");

        //Als het medewerkers account nog niet bestaat, maak hem dan aan
        if (medewerker == null)
        {
            medewerker = new IdentityUser()
            {
                UserName = "medewerker@test.nl",
                Email = "medewerker@test.nl",
            };
            //2de property is hier het wachtwoord
            await UserManager.CreateAsync(medewerker, "Ex4mple!");
        }
        //Voeg de gebruiker toe aan de desbetreffende
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(medewerker, "Medewerker");

    }
```

What is going wrong here?

I really hope someone with more experience in ASP.NET Core can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429168/9534819)

Comment: Or check this code sample [How Identity based DB context should look like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144)

Comment: Try `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();`